# Расширение для Visual Studio 2013 : вызов форматирования кода

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

Скажите пожалуйста как вызвать программно (из расширения к VS) форматирование (упорядочивание) кода, которое вызывается нажатием Ctrl+K+F ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короткий вариант - вызов по имени:

```
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatSelection"); // или "Edit.FormatDocument"
```

длинный - по ID:

```
var vsStd2KCmdGuid = VSConstants.CMDSETID.StandardCommandSet2K_string;
object customin = null, customout = null;

_applicationObject.Commands.Raise(vsStd2KCmdGuid, 
            (int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.FORMATDOCUMENT, 
             ref customin, ref customout);
```

`_applicationObject` - это инстанс`DTE2`. Для констант нужен референс на `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0`.

[Список ID для стандартных команд в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsstd2kcmdid(v=vs.120).aspx)

Вариант для VS Package, без использования `DTE2`:

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IVsUIShell uiShell = (IVsUIShell)GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell));

    var vsStd2KCmdGuid = VSConstants.CMDSETID.StandardCommandSet2K_guid;
    uint customin = 0;
    object customout = null;
    uiShell.PostExecCommand(ref vsStd2KCmdGuid, 
        (int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.FORMATDOCUMENT, 
        customin, ref customout);
}
```

Comment: `EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = this.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE80.DTE2)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;` возвращает null и ничего не работает поэтому. Хотя за способ спасибо. В будущем может пригодиться.

Comment: у вас уже должен быть готовый объект dte2 - он передается первым параметром в метод OnConnection при инициализации Addin. Т.е. я просто создал пустой AddIn с опцией "добавить tools menu item" и дописал в Exec одну строку. у вас тип проекта Addin или Package?

Comment: у меня тип проекта Package. А в чем разница между ними можете сказать?

Comment: @RussCoder это старый и новый способы интеграции  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139294/

Comment: @RussCoder Добавил вариант вызова через IVsUIShell - он проще в использовании в Package

Comment: спасибо. Теперь все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такое решение.

```
        DTE dte = this.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        TextDocument txt = (TextDocument)dte.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument");
        TextSelection txtSelection = txt.Selection;
        try
        {
            txtSelection.SmartFormat();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Форматирует, то что выделено. Но вот как сделать это для всего документа, пока что не нашел.